# How to get camera instance from cwac- cam2 for face detection?

Tags: android, android-camera, face-detection, cwac-camera

I would like to know how to get camera instance from CWAC- CAM2 library in android so that I can attach face detector to camera for face detection. Need know how to do this in android ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not supported by the library. Use the camera APIs directly, skipping the library.

Comment: Is it possible to do face detection using cwac-cam2 library ?

Comment: @AmanSrii: No. That library is a replacement for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` and `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`, and neither of those support face detection. Use the camera APIs directly, skipping the library.